# CMake, the c compiler unable to compile simple test program

Tags: c++, mingw32

I'm trying to compile my project using cmake with mingw but getting error:

```
     cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ../
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: D:/mingw/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: D:/mingw/bin/gcc.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:51 (message):
  The C compiler "D:/mingw/bin/gcc.exe" is not able to compile a simple test
  program.
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: what is your gcc version? gcc --version to get it. Usually that error happens because of old gcc versions.

Comment: gcc (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0

Comment: Can you check this and see if it's the case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38786190/7735711

Comment: still getting same error

Comment: My last hope is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25995788/7735711 apparently messed up $PATH can achieve this error too. If not, I don't know anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there are problems if the directory has any spaces in it's name, like yours has in "Program files". Try to copy the sdk to another location without spaces and see what happens