# CLion and Platformio: target not found. Configuration issues

Tags: cmake, arduino, target, clion, platformio

I followed this [link](http://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/ide/clion.html) to be able to use CLion for arduino projects using Platformio. I'm having two issues that I'll post here as I think that might be related.

**First Issue**

I'm getting stuck in the last step, which says

> Build project (DO NOT use “Run” button, see marks on the screenshot above): Menu: Run > Build.

As you can see in the next image, PLATFORMIO_BUILD target is broken and I can't run it.

[Build bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Duru.png)

Editing configurations looks like this, and I don't know if its meant to be like this. As you can see in the next image, the error says: Target PLATFORMIO_BUILD not found.

[Edit Configurations Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sp7rc.png)

I've repeated the procedure several times, with no luck. CLion is 2017.2.3 and Platformio is last version as well.

The project itself is fine, since if I run `platformio run --target upload` from the command line, the project compiles and is uploaded to the arduino.

**Second Issue**

All files in my project show a yellow header saying:

> This file does not belong to any project target, code insight features
>   might not work properly

Due to this, many of the benefits of using CLion are gone.

All these files, as well as the folders containing them are greyed out. I'm not sure if I should include them manually on CMAKELists, but as I understood, the command `platformio init --ide clion --board uno` already takes care of this.

It's first time using CLion and might be that the problem resides in some basic configuration I'm not aware of. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Checking the CMake log I was getting the following error:

> Error:The C compiler "/usr/bin/cc" is not able to compile a simple
>   test program. It fails with the following output:  Change Dir:
>   /Users/...         .../**default**/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp Run Build
>   Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_ab383/fast" xcrun: error: invalid active
>   developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun
>   at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun CMake will not
>   be able to correctly generate this project. Error:Configuration Debug
>   The C compiler "/usr/bin/cc" is not able to compile a simple test
>   program.

Same problem was found [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203856790-Clion-doesnt-compile-on-MacOS-Sierra), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25976001/the-c-compiler-usr-bin-c-is-not-able-to-compile-a-simple-test-program), and the solution in my case was to uninstall the Command Line Tools:

```
rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

and reinstall them again:

```
xcode-select --install
```